# Using AND and OR together on the IF function

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Hi all I have been trying to fin out how to use AND and OR together on the same formula.

I'm trying to resolve the following issue :

The person will get a discount only if they are working on the Cerrovial project or if they are working on the Parinas project but the risk of the job must be Low

I tried to use a formula and excel gave me an error and also fixed my formula but I do not know if this is correct or what the "*" means

`=IF(OR(D14="CerroVial",D14="Parinas")*AND(E14="Low"),"8%","")`

[image: This is the table]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were close:

```
=IF(AND(OR(D14="CerroVial",D14="Parinas"),E14="Low"),"8%","")
```

All the elements of the `AND` need to be in the `AND(...)`, just like for the `OR`, which you had done correctly.

Comment: YAY!! It works perfectly Thank you I was having a hard time trying to do this formula :)